# mysql to csv not getting in proper format

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following code to download mysql data in csv format.

```
    require_once("../database.php");

   //Enter the headings of the excel columns
   $contents="Database Id,Last Name,First Name,Middle Name,User Name,Email,Permanent Address,Communication Address,City,Zipcode,State,Country,Mobile,Birth Date,Gender,Council Number,College,Registering As,Selected,BAMS Year,Internship Place,PG Subject,PG Title,PHD Subject,PHD Title,Other As Student,Selected ,Practicing Since,Practitioner PG Subject,Practitioner PG Title,Practitioner PHD Subject,Practitioner PHD Title,Other As Practitioner,Clinic Address,Accommodation Selected,Payment Mode,Member Status,Password Changed,Form Submission Date,Registration Activation Date,Memebrship Expires On,Last Log In Date\n";


   $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT * from tablename ORDER BY RAND()");


   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query))
   {
   $contents.=$row['reg_id'].",";
   $contents.=$row['lname'].",";
   $contents.=$row['fname'].",";
   $contents.=$row['mname'].",";
   $contents.=$row['username'].",";
   $contents.=$row['email'].",";
   $contents.=$row['address'].",";
   $contents.=$row['comaddress'].",";
   $contents.=$row['city'].",";
   $contents.=$row['zipcode'].",";
   $contents.=$row['state'].",";
   $contents.=$row['country'].",";
   $contents.=$row['mobile_num'].",";
   $contents.=$row['birthdate'].",";
   $contents.=$row['gender'].",";
   $contents.=$row['council_num'].",";
   $contents.=$row['college'].",";
   $contents.=$row['education'].",";
   $contents.=$row['extra'].",";
   $contents.=$row['bamsyear'].",";
   $contents.=$row['interneeplace'].",";
   $contents.=$row['pgsubject'].",";
   $contents.=$row['pgtitle'].",";
   $contents.=$row['phdsubject'].",";
   $contents.=$row['phdtitle'].","; 
   $contents.=$row['otherdetails1'].",";
   $contents.=$row['practice'].",";
   $contents.=$row['practicesince'].",";
   $contents.=$row['pgsubjectp'].",";
   $contents.=$row['pgtitlep'].",";
   $contents.=$row['phdsubjectp'].",";
   $contents.=$row['phdtitlep'].",";
   $contents.=$row['otherdetails2'].",";
   $contents.=$row['clinicaddress'].",";
   $contents.=$row['accommodation'].",";
   $contents.=$row['payment_mode'].",";
   $contents.=$row['member_status'].",";
   $contents.=$row['pwchng_flag'].",";
   $contents.=$row['form_submission_date'].",";
   $contents.=$row['registration_date'].",";
   $contents.=$row['expiry_date'].",";
   $contents.=$row['last_login_date'].",";
   $contents.=$row['status']."\n";
   }

   // remove html and php tags etc.
   $contents = strip_tags($contents); 

   //header to make force download the file
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my_members_".date('d-F-Y').".csv");
   print $contents;
```

Now Problem I Am Facing are

- CSV gets downloaded, but data is not getting in appropriate columns....
- if anybody uses comma in datafield, csv gets disturbed columns (i mean data not get below appropriate column heading). what can be used instead of comma to excute this code ?

Comment: Use `fputcsv`! No need to put CSV together by hand.

Comment: i didn't get what are you saying...can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create CSVs by hand, use the existing [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/fputcsv) function:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my_members_".date('d-F-Y').".csv");
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_query)) {
    fputcsv($out, $row);
}
```

Comment: thnx..this is working, but problem is that it is fetching each column twice sidebyside ( like columns from left to right in csv are id,id,fname,fname,mname,mname,lname,lname....which should be id,fname,mname,lname) and secondly , no headings for columns are there in csv.

Comment: Because you're using `mysql_fetch_array`, see my code in comparison.

Comment: yes...it worked when changed from array to assoc...but till, heading in each column in csv is not there? what be the solution?

Comment: yes..thank you....it worked when changed from array to assoc...but till, heading in each column in csv is not there? what be the solution? i mean to say $contents in above my code as Headings of each column in csv...they are not getting in csv ..

Comment: `fputcsv($out, array('Database Id', 'Last Name', 'First Name', ...))`

Comment: can i skip some fields from database while downloading as csv ?

Comment: Of course you can, you are in full control of what is being output.